# Find the vertices of a line between two points with a given stroke width

Tags: math, graphics, clojure, shapes

I am currently trying to create a render of a path in clojure (although I am happy with answers in other languages if they're easy to understand). A simple explanation is that I want to draw a line between two points with a given thickness - however I only want to find vertices of the line so that I can output it to a Wavefront file (a 3d model file with the extension .obj).

So, for example given points A and B which can be joined up like so:
[image: A and B]

I wish to find points A1 and B1
[image: A1 and B1]

This could also be thought of given a border to a shape. For example given A, B, C and D:
[image: Shape]

I would wish to find A1, B2, C1 and D1:
[image: Shape1]

The actual shape would be much more complicated however and may have a few hundred points.

My original thought was to do an enlargement from the centre of the shape with a scale factor of less than 1, like so:

```
(defn shrink-pos [centre-x centre-y x y]
  (let [diff-y (- y centre-y)
        diff-x (- x centre-x)
        dist   (Math/sqrt (+ (* diff-y diff-y) (* diff-x diff-x)))
        n-x    (+ centre-x (* diff-x 0.8))
        n-y    (+ centre-y (* diff-y 0.8))]
    [n-x n-y]))
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The width of the border/stroke is not uniform and there is no border between the last point and the first which join to close the shape.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'thick' line:
Let's **AB** is vector from A to B.
**ab** is normalized (unit length) vector ([vector normalization](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html))
**ab** = normalized(**AB**)
**p** is perpendicular vector to **ab**

```
p.x = -ab.y, p.y = ab.x
```

needed points' coordinates:
**B'** = **B** + thickness * **p**
**A'** = **A** + thickness * **p**

For polygon offseting:
Let's two neighbour edges are AB and BC (intersecting in vertice B).
Find normalized (unit) vectors **ab** and **cb**.
Calc unit bisector vector
**b** = normalized(**ab** + **cb**)
Calc length of bisector segments as `l=d/sin(fi)`
 where d is offset, and fi is angle between vectors **b** and **ab**.
It could be found as:

```
fi = atan2(crossproduct(b,ab), dotproduct(b,ab))
```

And find offset polygon vertice (for inner and outer offset polygons):

**B**' = **B** + l * **b**

**B**'' = **B** - l * **b**

P.S. Don't forget about inner polygon vertice vanishing for large offsets and weird loops for non-convex polygons